# ng2-datepicker run function on date change

Tags: angular

I'm using ng2-datepicker
the html looks like this.

```
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"></datepicker>
```

I'm not sure how to run a function when the date is changed when using two-way data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (ngModelChange)="myHandler($event)"></datepicker>
```

`ngModelChange` will call the handler, and the value of `$event` will be the new value of the `ngModel`.